# What terms can be used to determine the state of a switch?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, I came to naming a variable in my PHP today. The variable was to contain information about the state of a switch, E.g - **on** and **off**.

However, I couldn't, for the life of me, think of what to name it. I ended up settling for **State**. But for arguments sake, what other words could I have substituted for State?

Comment: You could call it a [***toggle***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle): *computers : a setting that can be switched between two different options by pressing a single key, making a single choice from a menu, etc.*

Comment: "status" instead of "state" ? If the variable is a boolean refering to a HMI control, "checked" may fit.

Comment: Questions about the following topics ... are out of scope for this site: 
Naming, including naming programming variables/classes http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @TrevorD It's not so much about naming the variable, I settled that one in the end. That's just the context in which this question was conceived. It's more about a substitute word, for which there is a specific tag on this site.

Comment: @TrevorD But the first legitimate choice on that list is *Word choice and usage*. Is that not what the OP is asking?

Comment: @WS2  OP specifically stated he is "naming a variable in my [code]", and (on my reading) the rules specify "Naming, including naming programming variables/classes" as an exception to "Word choice".  That's why I voted to close it.  He's since contradicted himself and now says "It's not so much about naming the variable".  I have no more comment!

Comment: @TrevorD - there is no contradiction. Read the question again (you can see that I haven't edited the context in the edit history) - it states that I have already named it and settled on state. It then goes on to say, for arguments sake, what words can be substituted for state? Why the conflict man? It's a question, you have voted to close it. If others agree, they will vote too. I respect that.

Comment: @Lewis  Apologies - obviously I didn't take in the question properly. :-(

Comment: I personally would have called the variable *is-on*, and it would have values *true* or *false*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would have used ***position***. But it may be dated.

*The position of the switch was at **on/off***

Comment: I like this one.